# Remove a part of a path separated with dots

Tags: python, string

Given a path, e.g.

```
file_path = 'a.b.c.d.e'
```

I wish to remove the `e`.
This is what I did:

```
class_path = ('.').join(file_path.split('.')[0:-1])
```

Any more elegant way to do it?

Comment: You can omit the 0 from `[0:-1]` but other than that, this looks "elegant" enough to me. Wrap it in a function called `get_parent_path` if you don't think this is clear enough.

Comment: doted path? what you mean by "path"? Directory path? It looks like a regular string instead

Comment: @felipsmartins might as well look at it like a string. I send it to a mock_object function under 'path=file_path' so it takes care of that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply with [`str.rfind`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rfind) function:

```
file_path = 'a.b.c.d.e'
file_path = file_path[:file_path.rfind('.')+1]
print(file_path)   # a.b.c.d.
```

If trailing `.` is not needed - remove `+1` shifting:  (`file_path[:file_path.rfind('.')]`).

Comment: I dont think the OP wants that trailing period at the end

Comment: @KunalMukherjee, see the notation. Also the question says *remove the `e`* but not *remove the `.e`* (to be precise)

Answer (score 4):

```
import os
os.path.splitext(file_path)[0]
```

Comment: I liked it. It makes sense a lot considering the given context.

Comment: @felipsmartins simply importing a module just to split strings would be overkill

Comment: @KunalMukherjee how much "overkill" is it? :)

Comment: I would assume `os` is already imported anyway, since we're dealing with paths here, so that's not a deal-breaker. There is a difference though in the output in case `file_path` has no dots at all, which will return `file_path` here, but a nullstring in OP's own version. If that's a problem or even better I can't say.

Answer (score 3):

You could use **rpartition** for example, if you want to stick to [string methods](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_ref_string.asp):

```py
class_path = file_path.rpartition('.')[0]
```

Comment: WOW! I didn't know on `string.rpartition()`. I learned something new today.